# Drawable tinting vs ColorFilter

Tags: drawable, tint, colorfilter

is there any difference in using lollipop´s drawable tinting vs. applying ColorFilter to a drawable? The result is the same, and ColorFilter is backwards compatible, so is there something I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From What I understand tint is the same as colorfilter But slightly simpler, since you don't have to specify a Mode (which can be a little confusing) or initialize a colorfilter object.
note that setColorFilter needs either color+mode or a color filter object but setTint only needs color.